# Configuration - locked calls / threads on TomCat - Vendor says restart

Tags: tomcat

First, I am a .NET guy, so I'm a little out of my element here.

My client's vendor has an API for their product that is hosted in Tomcat.  The service seems to be "holding on" to requests that are days old.

My belief is that they do not have proper error handling within their API's code, and just get stuck in endless loops retrying requests over and over.  They won't say what the problem is, but rather just tell my client to restart Tomcat.

This has become such a problem that the vendor is now suggesting scheduling a task to do a daily restart of Tomcat.  However, there are services that call the API throughout the night, on-demand (from retail consumers).

Can the experts out there back me up on this?  I don't believe that there's anything inherently wrong with Tomcat that requires this restart.  There are too many "serious" applications built on top of it that would never tolerate this fault.  It *has* to be bad coding from them (the vendor).  Or are there known configuration / platform issues that could be leading to these "dead threads?"

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To analyze stuck threads you will need to take thread dumps and pass them to the vendor (or whoever wrote the code) for analysis. If you dont know how to take thread dumps, you can google to find out the procedure for your environment.
Stuck threads could be caused by say a thread holding onto a network resource and not letting go. Bad coding could be an issue too.
Restarting regularly is not the best option, but it could be a temporary workaround until you find a permanent solution.

Comment: I'm pretty sure bad coding is at the root of this.  I personally believe it's either a deadlock or an "infinite retry" error handling approach.  The thread dumps should at least help us point to the suspected methods.

Thanks for the tips!